# I am not receiving all the data in the req on JWT renew function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, redux

I created a function to renew my JWT but I'm not receiving all the data and I don't know why...

My auth.js route is:

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const { check } = require("express-validator");
const { validarCampos } = require("../middlewares/validar-campos");
const {
  crearUsuario,
  loginUsuario,
  revalidarToken,
  updateUserProfile,
} = require("../controllers/auth");
const { passwordVerification } = require("../helpers/passwordVerification");
const { validarJWT } = require("../middlewares/validar-jwt");

const router = Router();

router.post(
  "/new",
  [
    // middlewares
    check("name", "El nombre es obligatorio").not().isEmpty(),
    check("userName", "El nombre de usuario es obligatorio").not().isEmpty(),
    check("email", "El email es obligatorio").isEmail(),
    check("password", "El password debe ser de 6 caracteres").isLength({
      min: 6,
    }),
    check("password2", "Las dos contraseñas deben ser iguales").custom(
      passwordVerification
    ),
    check("country", "El país es obligatorio").not().isEmpty(),
    validarCampos,
  ],
  crearUsuario
);

router.post(
  "/",
  [
    // middlewares
    check("email", "El email es obligatorio").isEmail(),
    check("password", "El password debe ser de 6 caracteres").isLength({
      min: 6,
    }),
    validarCampos,
  ],
  loginUsuario
);

router.get("/renew", validarJWT, revalidarToken);

router.post("/updateprofile", validarJWT, updateUserProfile);

module.exports = router;
```

were I create the "`router.post("/updateprofile", validarJWT, updateUserProfile);`" route to update the user profile.

My auth.js controller is:

```
const { response } = require("express");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const Usuario = require("../models/Usuario");
const { generarJWT } = require("../helpers/jwt");

const crearUsuario = async (req, res = response) => {
  const { userName, email, password, password2 } = req.body;

  try {
    let usuario = await Usuario.exists({ email });

    if (usuario) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        ok: false,
        msg: "Ya existe un usuario con ese email",
      });
    }

    usuario = await Usuario.exists({ userName });
    if (usuario) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        ok: false,
        msg: "Ya existe un usuario con ese nombre de usuario",
      });
    }

    usuario = new Usuario(req.body);

    // Encriptar contraseña
    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
    usuario.password = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
    usuario.password2 = bcrypt.hashSync(password2, salt);

    await usuario.save();

    // Generar nuestro JWT
    const token = await generarJWT(
      usuario.id,
      usuario.name,
      usuario.email,
      usuario.userName,
      usuario.profilePicture,
      usuario.lupcoins
    );

    console.log(usuario.id);
    console.log(usuario.name);
    console.log(usuario.email);
    console.log(usuario.userName);
    console.log(usuario.profilePicture);
    console.log(usuario.lupcoins);

    res.status(201).json({
      ok: true,
      uid: usuario.id,
      name: usuario.name,
      email: usuario.email,
      username: usuario.userName,
      profilePicture: usuario.profilePicture,
      lupcoins: usuario.lupcoins,
      token,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      ok: false,
      msg: "Por favor hable con el administrador",
    });
  }
};

const loginUsuario = async (req, res = response) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const usuario = await Usuario.findOne({ email });

    if (!usuario) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        ok: false,
        msg: "El usuario con ese email no existe",
      });
    }

    // Confirmar los passwords
    const validPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(password, usuario.password);

    if (!validPassword) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        ok: false,
        msg: "Password incorrecto",
      });
    }

    // Generar nuestro JWT
    const token = await generarJWT(
      usuario.id,
      usuario.name,
      usuario.email,
      usuario.userName,
      usuario.profilePicture,
      usuario.lupcoins
    );

    res.json({
      ok: true,
      uid: usuario.id,
      name: usuario.name,
      email: usuario.email,
      username: usuario.userName,
      profilePicture: usuario.profilePicture,
      lupcoins: usuario.lupcoins,
      token,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      ok: false,
      msg: "Por favor hable con el administrador",
    });
  }
};

const revalidarToken = async (req, res = response) => {
  const { uid, name, email, username, profilePicture, lupcoins } = req;
  console.log(req);
  // Generar JWT
  const token = await generarJWT(
    uid,
    name,
    email,
    username,
    profilePicture,
    lupcoins
  );

  res.json({
    ok: true,
    uid: uid,
    name: name,
    email: email,
    username: username,
    profilePicture: profilePicture,
    lupcoins: lupcoins,
    token,
  });
};

const updateUserProfile = async (req, res = response) => {
  const { profilePictureURL, username, email } = req.body;

  try {
    const usuario = await Usuario.findOne({ email });

    if (usuario) {
      usuario.profilePicture = req.body.profilePicture;

      await usuario.save();

      return res.status(200).json({
        ok: true,
        profilePicture: usuario.profilePicture,
        msg: "Foto de perfil actualizada correctamente",
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      ok: false,
      msg: "Por favor hable con el administrador",
    });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  crearUsuario,
  loginUsuario,
  revalidarToken,
  updateUserProfile,
};
```

were I created the revalidarToken (renew token) function to renew the JWT but when I test on Postman I don't receive the email data:

[image: Postman screenshot with missing email data]

But even worse, when I test with my React frontend I receive a very strange data showing the values on different order in Redux every time I refresh.

Correct data when I logged in:

[image: Redux store correct data when I logged in]

But when I refresh I have different data and in different order, sometimes the email contains the username or the lupcoins has the profilePicture url, etc and I'm not receiving the email data:

[image: different data order and missing email data when I refresh]

I'm understanding that the req data is called throw the token and I'm sending the email data to the token but I have no idea why this is happening...

I appreciate a little help here, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Done! I did it by doing the following:

Backend auth.js controller:

```
const updateUserProfile = async (req, res = response) => {
  const { profilePicture, email } = req.body;

  try {
    const usuario = await Usuario.findOne({ email });

    if (usuario) {
      usuario.profilePicture = req.body.profilePicture;

      await usuario.save();

      return res.status(200).json({
        ok: true,
        profilePicture: usuario.profilePicture,
        msg: "Foto de perfil actualizada correctamente",
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      ok: false,
      msg: "Por favor hable con el administrador",
    });
  }
};
```